# 360 degree view in iOS application

Tags: ios

I am working in an iPhone application which requires to create a 360degree view of an image. Upon my search what i could find is that images taken of the image and the images are rotated in a view .

I would like to know if anyone has a good solution or any good tutorial on how to achieve a really good this work.

Thank you

Comment: Did you find any good way to do this ??

Answer (score 3):

something like this?
http://javieralog.blogspot.com/2012/03/japanoview-open-source-panorama-viewer.html

Comment: Hi,Javier, JAPanoview zooming not works on iphone5,5s,6,6+. For rest of device it works properly. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

There are many js (e.g. [here](http://code.google.com/p/jspanoviewer/), [here](http://www.cheetah3d.com/download/HTML5pano/index.html)) libraries available for 360 degree panorama view. You can use UIWebView along with those libraries to achieve this easily.

Comment: I am actually looking for something that does a 360 degree view of an object( for eg : cars, mobiles)

Comment: What do you mean by objects. You can always use 6-8 images for car, mobiles or whatever to create panorama view. I am using similar functionality in my app.